# Makefile wildcard / pathsubst quiestion

Tags: makefile, wildcard, substitution

I have NO idea why this isn't working... I have a simple directory with protobuf files in in.  I want to create a makefile rule to build the protobuf file if the corresponding *.pb.o file isn't in the obj build directory...

So...

```
PROTOBUF_ROOT_PATH := <my_work_dir>/pb
PROTOBUF_SRC := $(PROTOBUF_ROOT_PATH)/external/src
BUILD_OUTPUT_PATH := <my_work_dir>/bin/obj/

APP_PROTBUF_SRC = $(wildcard ${PROTOBUF_SRC}/*.proto)

PROTO_BUF_DEFS = ${pathsubst ${APP_PROTOBUF_SRC}/%.proto,${BUILD_OUTPUT_PATH}/%.pb.o,${APP_PROTBUF_SRC}}
```

and I have created a make target "foo" to print this out...
    foo:
        @echo ${PROTO_BUF_DEFS}

it prints out a blank line.. Yipee!
ideas would be much appreciated.. and be nice if I've missed something obvious!  it's monday.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using GNU make here although you don't say so.  If you run `ls <my_work_dir>/pb/external/src/*.proto` what do you see?  You can try using `$(info src = $(APP_PROTBUF_SRC)` on the next line after you set that variable to see what's in it.  I don't see any obvious typos (although you really should choose one way to describe protobuf not three different ones (PROTOBUF, PROTBUF, PROTO_BUF) just to keep your sanity) but if `PROTO_BUF_DEFS` is empty then the only way that can happen in this makefile is if `APP_PROTBUF_SRC` is empty.

Comment: It's *patsubst*, not *pathsubst*.